# Screen Savers: Windows .scr In Ubuntu?

Tags: 10.04, screensaver

Does anyone know if this is possible?  I'm a Star Trek fan, and there's this screensaver that's for Windows that mimics a Star Trek systems panel, and I'd love to have that on Ubuntu (so would some of my friends).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Many Windows screensavers can be run in Wine.

Assuming your screensaver is stored in your Downloads folder, just run `wine ~\Downloads\startrekscreensaver.scr /s` in your Terminal.

Windows screensavers have not been integrated into Linux so you won't be able to easily set them as your screensaver.

You could also try installing `xscreensaver-gl-extra` for more screensaver choices. Many of these screensavers come with configuration options that can be modified with the default gnome-screensaver; you will need you to install `xscreensaver` to change those options.

Answer (score 1):

Possibly via Wine; Windows screensavers aren't nicely compartmentalized like NDIS drivers, they're ordinary Windows programs with a different extension so Windows will know to install them as screensavers.